# VBA-delete shapes

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that creates shapes in page 2 when I write something in A1:A3 and places the textbox according to what I write in B1:B3, the problem is that when I delete the value of A1 I want the textbox to be deleted, but it doesn't delete the textbox. I also tried :   `Call getCaixas(Worksheets(2), Target.Address).Delete` after dim box as shape. In this option it did erase the textbox but then all the textboxes were created on the top of the page.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim box As Shape

If Target.Address = "Delete" Then getCaixas(Worksheets(2), Target.Address).Delete

    If Target.Count > 1 Or Not Sh.Index = 1 Or Len(Target) = 0 Then Exit Sub



    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B3")) Is Nothing Then
            Set box = getCaixas(Worksheets(2), Target.Offset(0, -1).Address)
            Select Case Target.Value
                Case Is = "financeiro"
                    box.Top = 20
                Case Is = "cliente"
                    box.Top = 150
                Case Is = "processos internos"
                    box.Top = 250
            End Select
        End If

        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A3")) Is Nothing Then
            Set box = getCaixas(Worksheets(2), Target.Address)
            Select Case Target.Address
                Case Is = "$A$1"
                    box.Left = 50
                Case Is = "$A$2"
                    box.Left = 200
                Case Is = "$A$3"
                    box.Left = 350
            End Select
            box.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Target.Value
        End If



    End Sub

    Function getCaixas(ws As Worksheet, CaixasName As String) As Shape
        Dim box As Shape
        On Error Resume Next
        Set box = ws.Shapes(CaixasName)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set box = ws.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 0, 100, 50)
            box.Name = CaixasName
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set getCaixas = box
    End Function
```

Comment: *'when I delete the value of A1'* seems to conflict with `Len(Target) = 0`

Comment: This is a **Workbook_SheetChange** but you are completely disregarding the **sh** (worksheet) parameter.

Comment: You're right but I have tried as the edit... with the delete part before the `len(target)=0` and it didn't work either

Comment: Have you tried `ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Delete`?

Comment: That doesn't work because then I only get the last textbox I write in A1:A3

Answer (score 0):

When you have to delete shapes in a given area, the easiest way to do it, is to loop over the shapes and to see the outliers.

The shapes in a given sheet are a collection. Thus, looping through them is easy.
Each shape has two important properties - `TopLeftCell` and `BottomRightCell`. These properties are of type range - thus they have row and column property.

Long story short - if you have a case like this:

[image]

and you want to delete every shape outside the `range("A1:C3")` (in yellow) then you can loop through every shape and check its `TopLeftCell.Row` and `BottomRightCell.Column` for being more than 3. If both are true, then delete it. Like this:

```
Sub KillShapes()

    Dim sh As Shape

    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        Debug.Print sh.Name
        Debug.Print sh.TopLeftCell.Address
        Debug.Print sh.BottomRightCell.Address

        If sh.TopLeftCell.Row > 3 And sh.BottomRightCell.Column > 3 Then
            Debug.Print sh.Name; " is deleted!"
            sh.Delete
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong:

```
If Target.Address = "Delete" Then
```

The Address property of a Range object will return a range address like "$A$1". If are looking for a cell value of "Delete" then it should be

```
If Target.Value= "Delete" Then
```

If you are looking for the Name of a named range, then

```
If Target.Name.Name = "Delete" Then
```