# Delete a Shape (Spin Button) based on Active Cell.Offset variable

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete the spin box relative to the active cell (Column A, same row).

I think the issue is in using .Value in the IF statement, .Address did not work .Value doesn't delete the active Check Boxes but it does delete all the other Check Boxes & Spin Buttons.

Spreadsheet Intended Use

In Column A there are check boxes with IF statements that when checked (true), add the date in the previous row +1 to current row Column B, a spin button in Column D (linked to column C) and a Spin Button in column F (linked to Column E). This coding is working.

When the check boxes are unchecked (False), I have code to clear the contents of the cells in that row using ActiveCell.Offset (the A column cell) and I want to delete the spin buttons so they can't be accidentally used to add values to cleared cells.

Another Submit button will simply copy the data entered by users and paste in another sheet for analysis. This button will also reset the sheet.

Below code is only trying to delete one Spin Button, I will copy, paste and update the offset for the second Spin Button when it works. The Spin Button with the red arrow should be the only one deleted.

Original code was found in the below post. I tried to adapt it to use a variable.

[VBA-delete shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018603/vba-delete-shapes)

[image: Options & Date]

```
Sub RemoveSpinBoxes()

    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim OptionOneSpin As Range

    Set OptionOneSpin = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)

    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        Debug.Print sh.Name
        Debug.Print sh.TopLeftCell.Address
        Debug.Print sh.BottomRightCell.Address

        If sh.TopLeftCell.Value = OptionOneSpin And sh.BottomRightCell.Value = OptionOneSpin Then
            Debug.Print sh.Name; " is deleted!"
            sh.Delete
        Else
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `OptionOneSpin`? I wouldn't advise using `activecell` as it may not be what you think it is.

Comment: @SJR Stepping through the code to when the variable is stored. Locals window: `OptionOneSpin`, Type `Range/Range`, expanding further into the `Validation` expression, `Value` = `True` Type `Boolean`. The `Column` & `Row` values are correct, they're being stored as `Long`.
I hope that's the answer, let me know if I'm looking in the wrong spot

Comment: I think some of your problem comes from the fact that an empty cell in Excel has an implicit value of 0 when evaluated, this is probably why your if-statement condition evaluates to TRUE every time.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Just copy, paste the block and offset differently for more shapes.

Sort of understand how it's working. As @DecimalTurn suggested in regards to the cells implicit value, it's returning a False now and that is why it's  working. Also using the intersect parameter makes it more reliable I guess?

[Solution source here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/delete-shape-picture-within-single-cell-in-vba.1009306/) Adapted from Bukimis second post.

```
Sub RemoveSpinButtons()

 Dim Shape As Shape

 For Each Shape In wsSpinButtons.Shapes
        If Not Intersect(Shape.TopLeftCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)) Is Nothing Then
            Shape.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
 Next Shape
End Sub
```